# How to integrate Hadoop, SOLR and Impala?

Tags: hadoop, solr, impala

I am looking for example or guidance on how to use Hadoop, SOLR and Impala together. Actually I know how to use Impala and Hadoop, but also want to use the power of SOLR to make the queries run faster. I explored the web pretty extensively but could not find anything that would put me into action.

Comment: What do you mean by making the queries return faster? Are you asking if you can use SOLR to improve the performance of Impala queries?

Comment: What you mean by saying queries return faster? More details

Comment: @Matt, Actually I wanted to use the trio Hadoop, SOLR and Impala together to get faster, real-time response. In other words, will it be productive if I use the three together ? Does Impala and Solr complements each other ?

Answer (score 0):

Solr and Impala complement each other in that Solr can help you understand your data's structure -- in other words, for initial discovery. From that point on, you can use that knowledge to write Impala queries that target one facet of the data or the other.